# Passing a collection of interface types to a function

Tags: interface, go

I'm having trouble figuring out the correct way to use interfaces in Go. My function needs to take a map of items that implement a certain method. It looks like this:

```
type foo interface {
    bar() string
}

func doSomething(items map[string]foo) {

}
```

I'm trying to call this function with a type that implements the `foo` interface.

```
type baz struct { }

func (b baz) bar() string {
    return "hello"
}

items := map[string]baz{"a": baz{}}
doSomething(items)
```

But I get the following error:

```
cannot use items (type map[string]baz) as type map[string]foo in function argument
```

However, it works fine when I do this:

```
items := map[string]foo{"a": baz{}}
doSomething(items)
```

But I want to reuse this same map against different interfaces. Basically I'm indexing a lot of objects and then passing them to various functions that require different interfaces implemented to compute results. I want to pass the map to one function as a map of `foo` and another function as a map of `foobar`.

I've tried various type assertions and conversions but nothing seems to work so I'm not sure if I'm just not using the correct syntax or just doing it completely wrong.

Go Playground at http://play.golang.org/p/8mMWCDG7vm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly common mistake.

You are mixing these two distinct types:

```
map[string]foo

map[string]baz
```

You cannot simply convert from one map type to another. The same goes with [converting `[]T` slices to `[]interface{}` slices](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/InterfaceSlice), or [converting `chan T` to `chan interface{}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623670/passing-a-channel-of-things-as-a-channel-of-interfaces-in-go) (same question/answer but for channels).

`map[string]foo` means a map of foo interfaces, not all types map[string]T where T implements the foo interface.

You can solve it by making this change:

```
items := map[string]foo{"a": baz{}}
```

**Playground:** http://play.golang.org/p/HxIVGSptwk

**Edit:**

Having a map of interfaces allows you to type cast the different interface values to other types of interfaces. So the map can be reused.

**Playground:** http://play.golang.org/p/20YMWmDjYT

But then you should have a map of an interface type that is the intersection of all the different methods implemented by the types to be stored in the map. If there is no intersection, then you will have to use `interface{}` to ensure that any type might be stored.

Comment: I knew that `map[string]foo` works (see my original question) but I was hoping I was missing something. What's the Go idiomatic way to deal with collections of structs that need to be passed around using interfaces? Do you recreate the entire map for each interface type? Create an interface for the map type somehow?

Comment: If you are going to pass it around, I'd suggest still keeping it as a map of interfaces. If you do, you can make a type cast the values to `foobar` when needed: See edit example.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Seems really weird to want interface foobar, but accept interface foo just so you can later convert it to the interface you want. Means no compile time type checking even though the desired interface type is static.

Comment: Yes, in that case it is weird. I just added to the edit that you might want to use a different interface for the map values to ensure that any type that should be stored in the map actually implements the interface. Like, if you will store io.Writer's and sometimes io.ReadWriter's, you want to use the io.Writer's interface because that is implemented by all types that you will store.